# Auto transmission shifting late, staying in low gear

Tags: automatic-transmission, shifting

The mother-in-law's 2005 Renault Clio (auto) shifts very late and stays in too low a gear. When decelerating the tranny downshifts early (it really likes the revs). The garages all want a heafty sum to even pop the hood. Might the issue be something simple such as low tranny fluid level? Anything else that I might check?

There is no 'sport' mode or 'snow' mode that I am aware of.

Thanks.

Comment: Having a good fluid level is always helping in any case. My automatic transmission is using a cable, I needed to readjust it when I had the same issue. But all car are not the same.

Comment: Check the fluid level. Also have a garage or parts store (Pep Boys, Autozone, etc) check the codes with their reader and see if anything comes up.

Comment: Thanks Gabreil and Peter. The fluid level is fine, and the fluid does not appear burnt or dirty. There are no Autozone-type stores here, I'm not in the US or Europe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should cause a DTC (Diagnostic Trouble Code) as it's remotely emissions related and can cause a loss of fuel economy. If you're sure that it's not in a mode that disables overdrive (and typically causes the car to stay in gear and shift late, for descending hills), then:

The first thing I would do is try and get a free or cheap code readout. That can point you in the right direction.

The second thing I would try is checking any [kickdown switch linkage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_control_unit#Kick_down_switch), or if electronically controlled, the throttle position sensor.